# Floating ip pool not found

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, openstack, ibm-cloud, openstack-horizon

I'm trying to use [vagrant-openstack-provider](https://github.com/ggiamarchi/vagrant-openstack-provider) to manage Bluemix VMs.

All is looking good, except for an error message at the end: `Floating ip pool not found.`

```
2015-09-27 11:17 | DEBUG | request  => method  : POST
2015-09-27 11:17 | DEBUG | request  => url     : https://api2-dal09.open.ibmcloud.com:8774/v2/.../os-floating-ips
2015-09-27 11:17 | DEBUG | request  => headers : {"X-Auth-Token"=>"...", :accept=>:json, :content_type=>:json}
2015-09-27 11:17 | DEBUG | request  => body    : {"pool":"private"}
2015-09-27 11:17 | DEBUG | response => code    : 404
2015-09-27 11:17 | DEBUG | response => headers : {:content_length=>"73", :content_type=>"application/json; charset=UTF-8", :x_compute_request_id=>"...", :date=>"Sun, 27 Sep 2015 10:17:30 GMT"}
2015-09-27 11:17 | DEBUG | response => body    : {"itemNotFound": {"message": "Floating ip pool not found.", "code": 404}}
2015-09-27 11:17 |  WARN | Error allocating ip in pool private : Floating ip pool not found.
2015-09-27 11:17 |  WARN | Impossible to allocate a new IP
ERROR warden: Error occurred: Floating ip pool not found.
```

Is it possible to create an IP pool in the horizon console?  If so, how do I do this?  I couldn't find any documentation online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I specified 'private' in the Vagrantfile:

```
os.floating_ip_pool   = 'private'
```

I should have been using 'Public-Network' instead:

```
os.floating_ip_pool   = 'Public-Network'
```

I didn't realise at the time, but you can find the floating_ip_pool with:

```
snowch$ vagrant openstack floatingip-list

+-------------------+
| Floating IP pools |
+-------------------+
| Public-Network    |
+-------------------+
```